# DB2 throw exception in case block

Tags: db2, db2-luw

In my trigger I want to throw an exeption, but it is not working properly, got exception. Using DB2 LUW

```
{0:0} An unexpected token "SQLSTATE '1234'" was found following "
        SIGNAL".  Expected tokens may include:  "<space>".. SQLCODE=-104, SQLSTATE=42601, DRIVER=4.28.11


CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "TRG_ABC_DELETE_CHECK"
 NO CASCADE BEFORE DELETE ON ABC
REFERENCING OLD AS OLD_OBJ
FOR EACH ROW MODE DB2SQL
BEGIN
    SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT 1 FROM ABC WHERE ID = 2 OR NAME = 'AA' AND OLD_OBJ.TYPE = 2) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '1234' ('Wrong Parameters');
    END FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMM1;
END
```

Comment: Share the entire code for the trigger, the Db2 platform and version. What was the event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use another statements (like SIGNAL) in the SELECT statement.
Use the [RAISE_ERROR](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-raise-error) function instead to make SELECT raise an exception conditionally.

Or use [CASE statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-case) instead of the [CASE expression](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=expressions-case-expression) you use in the question.